# Converting a tuple of integral_constants to a constexpr tuple of ints

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, constexpr, boost-hana

Suppose I have a tuple of `hana::integral_constant`s like so:

```
auto tuple_of_int_const = hana::make_tuple(hana::integral_constant<int,0>(),
                                           hana::integral_constant<int,1>());
```

I am trying to now produce a constexpr tuple of ints from this like so:

```
constexpr auto constexpr_tuple = hana::make_tuple(0,1);
```

My attempt:

```
#include "boost/hana.hpp"


using namespace boost;

auto tuple_of_int_const = hana::make_tuple(hana::integral_constant<int,0>(),
                                           hana::integral_constant<int,1>());

constexpr auto tuple = hana::transform(tuple_of_int_const,[](auto x){ return x(); });
```

The problem is that lambda's are not constexpr.......so the question is this:
How do I convert a tuple of `integral_constant`s to a constexpr lambda?

Note:

I am using c++14

Comment: Lambdas are constexpr when possible in current-day C++.

Comment: @chris I am sorry......I should have noted that I am using c++14.........I will edit to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create regular template function:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto tuple_transform(std::tuple<Ts...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(Ts{}()...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab58e12e2171b55e)

Comment: That is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Boost.Hana has the function [`value_of`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Constant.html#gab46a092deeb205f2c92c335d4312a991) as part of the [`Constant`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Constant.html) concept.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
  auto tuple_of_int_const = hana::make_tuple(hana::integral_constant<int,0>(),
                                             hana::integral_constant<int,1>());

  constexpr auto tuple = hana::transform(tuple_of_int_const, hana::value_of);

  static_assert(hana::make_tuple(0, 1) == tuple, "");
}
```